# Compilation error "4:12: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression" / problems with defining dynamic in prolog

Tags: dynamic, compiler-errors, prolog, gnu-prolog

Please help.
I'm encounter this compilation error in GNU prolog, when I use SWISH it looks like code compile but when I try to
?- current_room(X). it shows me error anyway (just false), so I expect something is not right with way I defined dynamic.

```
% Rooms

:- dynamic current_room/1.



room(kitchen).
room(hall).
room(living_room).
room(dinning).


path(kitchen,dinning,n).
path(kitchen,hall2,e).

path(hall,living_room,s).

path(living_room,hall,n).
path(living_room,hall2,s).
path(living_room,dinning,w).

path(dinning,living_room,e).
path(dinning,kitchen,s).

path(hall2,living_room,n).
path(hall2,pantry,s).

path(pantry,hall2,n).


objects(couch).

in_room(living_room,couch).



route(room).

%(current_room,Destination, X).

%asserta(current_room(Destination)).

move(X) :- current_room(Z), path(Z,Y,X), retractall(my_pos(Z)), assert(my_pos(Y)).
n :- move(n).
s :- move(s).
w :- move(w).
e :- move(e).

start :- write('Type n/s/e/w'),nl, asserta(current_room(hall2)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU prolog have different syntax `:- dynamic(current_room/1).`.

Comment: Yes, `dynamic` is an "operator" in SWI-Prolog.

Comment: GNU Prolog syntax is compliant with the ISO Prolog Core standard, which doesn't require the atom `dynamic` to be declared as an operator.